# Badge progress display like the Percentage Till privilages display

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

Can we have a Progress percentage or indicator that shows how much of a remaining **__** till the badge. Like we have the percentage reputation displayed  till privilege  in the privileges tab.

It seems odd that progress indicator for one aspect and not for the other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been brought up [many times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=progress%20badges) on Meta.StackOverflow and rejected. The posts are now closed as duplicates tracing back to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report).

Comment: Thanks for the links to the dupes :)

Comment: The answer to that question on MSO was curious to me, so I posted a question about this on GameDev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/why-not-show-progress-towards-achievements-badges. (FYI)

Comment: +1 for posting link here